# Form builder app database design adding versioning

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, postgres

i'm making a custom form builder app similar to google forms or wufoo and i've completed the basic database design. However there is one thing i can't figure out. I'd like to keep track of version of each built form. Like if there is a change in an existing form i don't want to just update it to lose old form design, i want to keep the old design and save the new one with a new version number. How can achive the versioning?

Here is what i have so far:
[image]

Each `Application` is a form design, `Page` is a page in the form, `Form` is a section of the page and `FormComponent` is the component (textbox, radio, select, ...)

Comment: A simple solution is to handle the new version of an older form simply like as if it was a new form. If your forms currently have a name as unique identifier, change this to name + version number being the unique id.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of options with associated trade offs:

- Create a new explicit version of the form for each change - and
  snapshot each element of the form for each change.  Lots of records,
  but easy to implement and recall.
- Create a new explicit version of
  the form, but only associate changed records with the new version.
  Fewer records, easy to implement, complex queries to recall.  I'm not
  a fan of this, because it makes the foreign keys implicit which makes
  for confusing architecture.
- Make all tables date effective (implicit
  versioning).  Fewer records, but complex queries.  You need all the
  joins to take into account the date.  Most databases can handle this
  efficiently.  See [Version controlling a database's contents](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/280203/version-controlling-a-databases-contents?rq=1)
  for an example of this.